# performance bottleneck with requests to third-party API from nodejs

Tags: node.js, performance, api

I'm using third-party API in my nodejs app.

The first, when I do `hey -c 20 -z 30s -cpus 1 http://api_url.com`, I get about `Requests/sec:  57`.

Raw API response is about 275000 symbols (UTF8) (api response is `JSON`).

The simplified example of my app:

```
const req = () => {
  const url = 'http://api_url.com';
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const r = http.get(
      url,
      (res) => {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        let rawData = '';
        res.on('data', chunk => {
          rawData += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', () => {
          const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
          resolve(parsedData);
        });
      });
  });
}

koaRouter.get("/", async (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.type = "html";
  const data = await req();
  ctx.body = data;
});

app.use(koaRouter.routes()).use(koaRouter.allowedMethods());

app.listen(9000, () => {
  console.log("\n--------- Started ---------");
});
```

If I run `hey -c 20 -z 30s -cpus 1 http://localhost:9000` then I get about `Requests/sec:   15`.

I think it related to large API response, because if I stop each request after the getting of the first chunk:

```
res.on('data', chunk => {
  resolve('end');
  r.abort();
});
```

the running of `hey ....` provides about `Requests/sec: 50`.

I know that I can run nodejs app in cluster mode, but is it possible to increase `Requests/sec` in my case (if run in `fork` mode)?

Comment: @llya Can you give some brief on this `hey -c 20 -z 30s -cpus 1 `, I never see anything like this before.

Comment: @SachinShah it ls just HTTP load generator. Please see https://github.com/rakyll/hey